# How do I use multiple selector tags to exclude them from dbt run

Tags: dbt

I need to exclude a few selector tags in the dbt run, instead to excluding models which are more in number compared to tags.

I am running

```
 dbt run --fail-fast --profiles-dir . --exclude tag:selector1,tag:selector2,tag:selector3
```

getting error:

```
The selection criterion '[tag:selector1,tag:selector2,tag:selector3]' does not match any nodes
```

my selector entry looks like:

```
selectors:
  - name: selector1
    definition:
      union:
        - intersection:
          - method: tag
            value: selector1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

selectors and tags are two different things. There is no such thing as a "selector tag." It's hard for me to understand exactly what you're trying to do, but to explain the building blocks:

*tags* are configs that can be applied to any dbt resource (e.g., models, seeds, tests). I can add a tag to a model like this:

```sql
-- my_model.sql
{{ config(tags=['tag1', 'tag2']) }}
select 1
```

I can then run this model (and all other models with `tag1`) with:

```bash
dbt run -s tag:tag1
```

I can run all models tagged with *either* `tag1` or `tag2` by using union syntax (a space):

```bash
dbt run -s tag:tag1 tag:tag2
```

Or I can run only the models tagged with *both* `tag1` and `tag2` by using intersection syntax (a comma):

```bash
dbt run -s tag:tag1,tag:tag2
```

If this gets too complicated, instead of typing in this selection syntax every time at the command line, I can define a [custom selector](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors#exclude) in a .yml file, and reference that selector in my CLI command.

Here's a yml selector for *either* `tag1` *or* `tag2` (union):

```yaml
selectors:
  - name: union_tag1_tag2
    description: *either* `tag1` *or* `tag2`
    definition:
      union:
        - method: tag
          value: tag1
        - method: tag
          value: tag2
```

I would then use this selector at the command line like this:

```bash
dbt run --selector union_tag1_tag2
```

And again, for my second example above, for just models with *both* `tag1` and `tag2` (intersection):

```yaml
selectors:
  - name: intersection_tag1_tag2
    description: *both* `tag1` and `tag2`
    definition:
      intersection:
        - method: tag
          value: tag1
        - method: tag
          value: tag2
```

Then I use the new name at the command line:

```bash
dbt run --selector intersection_tag1_tag2
```

I can use `--exclude` with `tag:`

```bash
dbt run --exclude tag:tag1
```

But I can't use `--exclude` with a selector. Instead, I define a selector that [does the excluding](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors#exclude):

```yaml
selectors:
  - name: exclude_intersection_tag1_tag2
    description: run all models except those tagged with *both* `tag1` and `tag2`
    definition:
      exclude:
        intersection:
          - method: tag
            value: tag1
          - method: tag
            value: tag2
```

Then I run it with:

```bash
dbt run --selector exclude_intersection_tag1_tag2
```